# Can I restore windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8

If I install Ubuntu over windows 8, and have a backup restore point or something, is it possible to go back to windows 8? I have a netbook, and it's not quite big enough to dual boot, and I don't want to install Ubuntu and be stuck trying to pay to get windows 8 back if I needed to. I do have another computer for most of my windows stuff, but its on vista which might be a bit outdated for some things I need, I'm just trying to improve the functionality (mainly boot time and speed) of this computer.

Comment: Instead of repeatedly installing and removing operating systems, it would be clever to dual boot both Ubuntu and Windows 8 on your netbook like this: [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported). That way you can boot the netbook to either OS.

Answer (score 0):

use the live disc and select 'Try Ubuntu'. If it works fine then you can permanently install it and replace windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

I you remove / replace Windows, that will remove it & it's restore points as well, so no..

I have a netbook & it dual boots very nicely, you could upgrade your HDD perhaps? Or, you could add a USB drive with the Linux OS on that, you're tied to having the drive but it's an easy upgrade.

If you have a lot of data you'd want to access from both OS's you could create another FAT32 partition & access it from both, saving duplication & space.

You *could* take a disk image of Windows, replace it altogether, & revert from the back-up image if you wanted - this would be mountable from an external drive, so you could access data within it. The details have been answered elsewhere - [like here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590973/copy-an-image-of-a-disk-to-an-external-drive).

Comment: thanks. I ended up just installing over windows and it works fine, for the most part.